# Overlapping texts in two pages?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I'm currently writing my Ph.D. thesis and my text must have two front pages as sketched bellow:

[image]

The texts on the yellow rectangles of both pages will be same and must occupy the exactly same position on both pages.

- On the top yellow rectangle I must put the name of university and the name of the program etc.;
- on the midle yellow rectangle I must put the title of the work;
- on the bottom yellow rectangle I must write the year.

My question is, how can I put the text on the green rectangle so that the texts on the yellow rectangles become overlapped?

Also, how can I get the backspacing of the text in the green rectangle?

Thanks.

Comment: By "overlapped", do you mean placed at the same position on both pages? What do you mean by "backspacing"?

Comment: Please provide example code that produces the two title pages. Also: what is the content of the green block?

Comment: @TorbjørnT, yes. I don't know if this is really called backspacing, but I refer to this large spacing from the left margin.

Comment: @Marijn I'll do it soon.

Comment: @Dion, it looks like an `ABNT`+ requirement. Take a look at the `abntex2` class or the `abnt` package.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the elements that are present to be positioned at the exact same places on each page. I'm not sure exactly what you want but your best bet may be absolute positioning of elements with Tikz. This is one way anyhow.

You can then replicate the page with or without certain elements. Something like the below (in this code I have redefined a set of coordinates so that the center of the page is 0,0 and it goes from -1 to +1 horizontally and vertically as illustrated - this may make it easier to specify positions -- or you could use other methods)

Something like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% ------------------
% |(-1,1)    (0,1)    (1,1)|
% |                        |
% |(-1,0)    (0,0)    (1,0)|
% |                        |
% |(-1,-1)   (0,-1)  (1,-1)|
% ------------------
\makeatletter
\def\parsecomma#1,#2\endparsecomma{\def\page@x{#1}\def\page@y{#2}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{page}{
    \parsecomma#1\endparsecomma
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{north east}
    % Save the upper right corner
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
    % save the lower left corner
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{south west}
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    % Transform to the correct placement
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@xc-\pgf@xb)/2.*\page@x+(\pgf@xc+\pgf@xb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@x\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@yc-\pgf@yb)/2.*\page@y+(\pgf@yc+\pgf@yb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@y\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,every node/.style={anchor=center}]
\node [fill = green, anchor = west, minimum height = 6mm, minimum width = 0.4\paperwidth, align = flush left,  inner xsep = 3mm, text width=0.40\paperwidth-5mm] at (page cs:-0.2,0.0) {The cat sat on the mat etc etc the dog sat on the cat and the pig sat with the frog The cat sat on the mat etc etc the dog sat on the cat and the pig sat with the frog};
\node [fill = yellow, anchor = north, minimum height = 6mm, minimum width = 0.7\paperwidth, align = flush left,  inner xsep = 3mm, text width=0.70\paperwidth-5mm] at (page cs:0.0,0.9) {The cat sat on the mat etc etc the dog sat on the cat and the pig sat with the frog The cat sat on the mat etc etc the dog sat on the cat and the pig sat with the frog};
\node [fill = yellow, anchor = north, minimum height = 6mm, minimum width = 0.7\paperwidth, align = flush left,  inner xsep = 3mm, text width=0.70\paperwidth-5mm] at (page cs:0.0,0.7) {The cat sat on the mat etc etc the dog sat on the cat and the pig sat with the frog The cat sat on the mat etc etc the dog sat on the cat and the pig sat with the frog};
\node [fill = yellow, anchor = north, minimum height = 6mm, minimum width = 0.7\paperwidth, align = flush left,  inner xsep = 3mm, text width=0.70\paperwidth-5mm] at (page cs:0.0,-0.7) {The cat sat on the mat etc etc the dog sat on the cat and the pig sat with the frog The cat sat on the mat etc etc the dog sat on the cat and the pig sat with the frog};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Dion, you can accept Aubrey's answer if it helped you.